# jQuery content slider with start/stop/resume functionality

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jQuery content slider plug-in out there with start/stop functionality as well as an auto-resume functionality?

I basically want the plug-in to cycle through content and have the ability to pause it. After 5 minutes of it being paused I want the ability to auto-resume the sliding.

Answer (score 0):

There is a pretty good jQuery Slider called Coda-Slider 2.0. It has an autoplay function and can cycle through things cyclicly as well.

http://plugins.jquery.com/project/Coda-Slider

The plugin itself doesn't look to difficult to decipher so you could probably add a pause/play  button and then write some extra javascript like interval to tell it to resume after a set period of time. Not sure if this is exactly what you need but check it out.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for carousels, there are so many plugins in the wild. Check [easy slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding) and [anything slider](http://css-tricks.com/examples/AnythingSlider/) as an example.